# Migration of Perl Code to Windows: Missing Udunits Package?

Tags: windows, perl, compilation

We have some very old Perl scripts doing some database work; the scripts run in a Linux environment, which is going obsolete. One Perl script with .pl loads a package (with .pm extension); the .pm file has code like:

```
use UDUNITS;
```

My development environment is a Windows machine with ActivePerl 5.2 installed. I think I am able to load other Packages fine except I can't find the UDUNITS package in a Windows binary.

There IS a way to compile UDUNITS2 package, per http://fossies.org/linux/udunits/udunits2.html#Windows but I am unable to compile using CMake--getting errors. My first time with CMake.

So what are my options? I don't want to develop on Linux because I don't have the expertise; and also I think going past the UDUNITS problem may be all I need in Windows.

Thanks!

**Update** I used command line way now: cmake CC="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" CXX="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" -DEXPAT_LIBRARY=c:\expat32\Bin\libexpat.dll ..
and I can see that 'configuring done' and 'generating done' but also a message like CUNIT not found. Build files are written to a folder; *but where is the DLL*? I am quite new to this so sorry if too simple questions.

Comment: you might want to retitle to installing UDUNITS for win32

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use the CPAN versions of UDUNITS2 as a drop in replacement? There look to be two:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Physics::Udunits2

https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::UDUNITS2

Comment: Let me try your links; I think udunits2 should be fine but the Package Manager could not find that--think. thanks.

Comment: How do I use this: From the Physics version, I downloaded the .pm file, put it along the same level as the other .pm file and then include this line in the calling .pm file: use Physics::Udunits2; but I see cannot localte object for module physics.Udunits2 ; sorry, very tired by now to

Comment: I don't think your Answer will work because the Physics and the Alien UDUNITS2 modules are dependent on the other UDUNITS2 module.

Comment: There's a few compiled DLLs around on cygwin and other domains (google 'udunits2.dll') that might be able to be dropped in if you can't get the compilation steps working, but I can't vouch for compatibility/safety. You haven't provided any detail on the compilation issues you're facing so noone can help you with them.

Comment: Too many errors were there in compilation to list here. I have just now installed the MinGW packages and now errors are few--only down to missing Expat libraries; I am working that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do? What do you really need? because there are pure perl alternatives

- [Math::Calc::Units - Human-readable unit-aware calculator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Calc::Units)
- [Physics::Unit - Manipulate physics units and dimensions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Physics::Unit)
- [DateTime - A date and time object for Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)
- http://perl.plover.com/units/units
- [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) / [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) ... because [udunits2-derived.xml](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-2.2.19/udunits/udunits2-derived.xml)

Comment: I don't understand the legacy PERL code and nor is there time to go through the code; we simply need to deploy to another place. In the code, after loading the UDunits package, there is a command like UDUNITS::init(data.dat) file; the .dat file has various measurements like 'degree_Celsius  S kelvin @ 273.15' etc. I thought, by simply loading the UDUnits package, I would have to worry about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, with good  folks' help from Github (as seen at: https://github.com/Unidata/UDUNITS-2/issues/18 ), I am now able to compile using the following:
1) Downloaded from Source Forge the Expat 32 library into c:\expat32

2) Downloaded the UDUNITS2 from https://github.com/Unidata/UDUNITS-2 and unzipped on a local folder.

3) Downloaded and Installed CMake 3.2 with command line options

4) Ran the following two commands from within a newly created 'build' folder inside the unzipped folder from step #2:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:\expat32 -G "Visual Studio 11" -DEXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\expat32\Source\lib -DEXPAT_LIBRARY=c:\expat32\Bin\libexpat.lib

cmake --build . --config Release
```

and now I can see udunits2.dll inside: UDUNITS-2-master\build\lib\Release

folder.
Now, I need to figure out how to use this DLL inside my PERL script...

Thank you all for the help!