# Using a Custom Made .DLL inside Active Perl Scripts?

Tags: windows, perl, dll, load

For background info, please see this: [Migration of Perl Code to Windows: Missing Udunits Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657170/migration-of-perl-code-to-windows-missing-udunits-package)

As you can see, I have managed to create three files: udunits2.dll, udunits2.lib, and udunits2.exp and I have copied them to another Windows box with Active Perl installed. I copied the three files into c:\windows\system32 and into C:\Perl64\bin and relative to the calling Perl .pm file but no luck. I have tried syntax like:

```
my $UDUNITS2 = Win32::LoadLibrary('C:\Perl64\bin\udunits2.dll');
if(not defined $UDUNITS2) {
  die "Can't import API UDUNITS2";# this doesn't get hit
}
use UDUNITS2;# error happens here.
```

The original (Linux code) was using an older udunits library; I have managed to compile udunits2, per the linked S.O page.

When I run this code I get: Cannot load UDUNITS2.pm in @INC

I must be way off?! My guess is that the my DLL is missing some .Def (definition) file and that's why the Perl engine can't find it? Note, I think the udunits2.dll itself is probably okay because I have followed the instructions.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use UDUNITS2;# error happens here.

Where did you get this perl module?

UDUNITS2.pm.... and supporting files is what is supposed to interface to udunits2.dll/.lib...

example of how that works is [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html)/[SOso-0.01.patch.txt](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=921357)

LoadLibrary is practically never used for this

**update: 2015-04-21-19:28:42**

You claim your code depends on a perl module UDUNITS2.pm but there is no such module available on cpan (or the internet) that I could find.

There is a perl module on cpan  called Physics::Udunits2.

The perl module Physics::Udunits2  is an interface the dynamic link library udunits2.dll//.lib, the one that come from http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/ (from here on referred to as unidata/udunits2 )

Compiling unidata/udunits2 using sh/configure/gcc... does not mean you have installed Physics::Udunit2, Physics::Udunit2 requires its on installation step , a step that also includes compilation/linking using gcc and produces a .dll, one which links to the dll from unidata/udunits2.

SOso-0.01.patch.txt is an example of the simplest perl xs module, one which requires compilation and produces a .dll, but it doesn't link to other libraries 9 like unidata/udunits2)

https://metacpan.org/source/HEIKOK/Physics-Udunits2-0.03/README explains the basic steps
To install this module type the following:

```
   perl Makefile.PL
   make
   make test
   make install
```

Important for you is to read/edit https://metacpan.org/source/HEIKOK/Physics-Udunits2-0.03/Makefile.PL

Makefile.PL is where Physics::Udunits2 tells ExtUtils::MakeMaker where to find/link udunits2.h and libudunits2, so it can compile Physics::Udunits2  and link against unidata/udunits2

Make sense now? Open Makefile.PL and edit INCLUDE/LIBS to something like

```
#~     LIBS              => ["-L$udunits_lib_path".' -ludunits2 -lm'], # e.g., '-lm'
#~     LIBS              => ["-L/path/to/udunits2dotlib  -llibudunits2.lib" ],
    LIBS              => [ "-l/full/path/to/libudunits2.lib" ],
#~     INC               => "-I. -I$udunits_inc_path",
    INC               => "-I. -I/path/to/udunits2doth",
```

Its also a good idea to rename the .dll from unidata/udunits2 to something like libudunits2.dll ... because Physics::Udunits2  will generate a Physics/Udunits2.dll of its own.

Comment: i cant test till tomorrw.. but are you sure? Mine is a Windows system and I compiled the Dll myself. How do I make a .pm file? thx

Comment: How can your code have  `use UDUNITS2;` if the module doesn't exist? This isn't compatible with what you said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657170/

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand how the 'modules' should work. As you can see, udunits module was missing in Windows and so compiled a new udunits2.dll, hoping that I could call that in the script. Are you saying that, somehow, I could convert udunits2.dll to udunits2.pm file? Thanks.

Comment: I think I am going to accept your Answer; going to compile to a Windows DLL from the source was probably not the correct route for me; I should have used something to make to UDUNITS2.pm file instead. Thanks.

Comment: udunits2.lib/udunits2.dll is called a library, a dynamic link library ... the perl module https://metacpan.org/pod/Physics::Udunits2 interfaces the udunits2.lib library,  but if you're having problems compiling that existing one, creating a replacement from scratch is going to be harder (perlxstut is long).  otoh like I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29667782/2335842 most of the udunits magic is available from other libraries

Comment: But I HAVE compiled udunits2 to udunits2.dll and udunits2.lib files! So are you saying that I could use the Physics::Udunits2 to interface with my compiled udunits2.lib? How? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Optional: I had moved on to making this all work in a Linux environment and made great progress there. I may still try your code at some later point in Windows--just to learn something new. Thank you very much!